# The Collatz sequence, $\xi$ records

Tags: collatz-conjecture

Consider the $3n+1$ sequence.

Let be $\sigma(n)$ the Number of steps necessary to reach the maximum of the trajectory starting from an integer $n$.

Let $\tau(n)$ be the Number of steps necessary to reach $1$ starting from $n$, I think that this is called the delay.

Now consider $\sigma(n)-\tau(n)=\gamma(n)$, that is the number of steps from the maximum to $1$.

Now consider $\xi(n)=\frac{\gamma(n)}{n}$

Now I call an integer $N$ a $\xi$ -record if for all $n<N$ we have $\xi(N)<\xi(n)$

> a) Does this produce a sequence of records?
> b) Can this sequence be useful for the $3n+1$ problem?

> c) Is there already an OEIS sequence?

Comment: You would have to work out some initial terms to check in OEIS.  Another "Collatz records" sequence there is [OEIS A025587](https://oeis.org/A025587), based on blowout factors for different starting points - the highest ratio of maximum term reached to starting point.

Comment: Do you have some data examples? Perhaps provide some?

Comment: you'll probably find powers of $2$ in that sequence, since it maximize $N$ and minimize $\gamma(N)$

Comment: Hmm, isn't $\tau(n)$ always larger than $\sigma(n)$, so $\gamma(n)$ is always negative?

Comment: @Gottfried Helms, since it was described as "the number of steps", and I see no reason to make it a negative number, I assumed it to be positive (and that the inversion was just a small mistake). But now that you ask, I am wondering if it was intentional....

Comment: and the record $7$ with $|\gamma(N)|=1.571428...$ seems hard to beat (any link with $\log_2(3)=1.5849...$?)